# Why does my program skip the first function? (Beginner C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop, break

I don't understand why `getAges` is being skipped.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cctype>
    using namespace std;

    int getAges(int age, const int SIZE);
    char getChoice();
    void displayInOrder(int numbers[], const int SIZE, char choice);
    void displayInReverse(int numbers[], const int SIZE, char choice);

    int main()
    {
        const int SIZE = 5;
        int numbers[SIZE] = { 1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5 };
        char answer;
        int age;
        char choice;


            if (toupper(choice) == 'O')
        {
            displayInOrder(numbers, SIZE, choice);

        }
        else if (toupper(choice) == 'R')
        {
            displayInReverse(numbers, SIZE, choice);

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid entry! - Must be O or R\n\n";

        }
        if (toupper(answer) == 'Y')
        {
            system("cls");

            age = getAges(age, SIZE);
            choice = getChoice();
            displayInOrder(numbers, SIZE, choice);
            displayInReverse(numbers, SIZE, choice);

            cout << "Run program again (Y or N)?  ";
            cin >> answer;
            break;
        }
        else if (toupper(answer) == 'N')
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int getAges(int age, const int SIZE)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << SIZE << " ages: \n\n";
        cin >> age;
        cout << endl;
        cin >> age;
        cout << endl;
        cin >> age;
        cout << endl;
        cin >> age;
        cout << endl;
        cin >> age;
        cout << endl;
        return age;
    }

    char getChoice()
    {
        char choice;
        cout << "How do you want to see the ages displayed? \n\n Enter O for In Order, or R for In Reverse.\n\n";
        cin >> choice;

        return choice;

    }

    void displayInOrder(int numbers[], const int SIZE, char answer)
    {
        cout << "Here are the ages in order: \n\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            cout << numbers[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    void displayInReverse(int numbers[], const int SIZE, char answer)
    {
        cout << "Here are the ages in reverse order: \n\n";
        for (int i = SIZE - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            cout << numbers[i] << endl;
        }
  }
```

Comment: "program goes directly to the choice function," do you mean `getChoice`? This is because it's being called in the while statement.

Comment: If I want the choice entered in `getChoice` to perform 2 separate functions depending on input, should I just make 2 while loops for `'O`' and `'R'` instead of nested if's ?

Comment: Ditch the while loops and use `if` or `switch` statements.

Comment: Updated post with no while loops but it still skips `getAges` and goes straight to `getChoice`

Comment: How do you assign to `answer`?

Comment: assignment operator `=`

Comment: It looks like you set it to `0` and only call `getAges` when `answer == 'Y'`

Comment: updated again, removed the `0` assignments, it's still skipping `getAges` for me though. I appreciate the help by the way, been stuck on this project for 7 hours

Comment: Your edits have made your question make no sense at all.  You ask about while loops, but there are none anymore, and because there aren't the break statements make your code not compile. Since choice and answer aren't initialized there's no telling what your program will do, and no guarantee it will ever do the same thing twice.

Comment: Thanks for the input, completely forgot about changing the title. So should I initialize choice and answer to 0 then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started working on this before the OP updated the title to their original question about "while loops & break statements". However at the time I came across this question the OP had originally removed the while loops. I was looking over the provided functions to get an idea of what the OP was trying to do and this is what I have come up with.

> - **First:** `while loops` are exactly what you want here, but you want a specific type of `while loop`, a `do-while loop` in this case.
> - **Next:** There is no need for `break` statements if you know how to structure your `do-while loop` correctly.
> - **Finally:** I made some modifications to the OP's existing `functions` by changing or removing unnecessary `parameter(s)`, `return type(s)` & `code duplication`. I removed a `function` that was no longer needed. I changed the `output formatting` of the messages to display a clean looking program. I also removed a bad practice of having `using namespace std;` in the global scope.

I did this to demonstrate to the OP how a while loop can be constructed without the need of break statements and that they were originally on the right track but needed a little bit of assistance to get on their way.

Here is the source code to a working program on what I think the OP was aiming to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

void getAge( int& age );
void displayInOrder( int numbers[], const int SIZE);
void displayInReverse( int numbers[], const int SIZE );

int main() {
    const int SIZE = 5;
    int numbers[SIZE] = { 0 };
    char answer = '\0';
    int age = 0;
    char choice = '\0';

    std::cout << "========================================================================\n"
              << "This program will have the user enter in "
              << SIZE
              << " Ages. \nThen ask the user in which order to display the list of ages.\n"
              << "Finally the program will ask the user if they want to continue or not.\n"
              << "========================================================================\n\n";

    do {

        for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ) {
            getAge( age );
            numbers[i] = age;
        }

        std::cout << "\nPlease enter 'O' for ordered or 'R' for reversed list.\n";
        std::cin >> choice;

        if ( toupper( choice ) == 'O' ) {
            displayInOrder( numbers, SIZE );
        }

        if ( toupper( choice ) == 'R' ) {
            displayInReverse( numbers, SIZE );
        }

        std::cout << "\nDo you want to run program again (Y/N)?";
        std::cin >> answer;

    } while ( toupper( answer ) == 'Y' );

    return 0;
}

void getAge( int& age ) {
    int temp;
    std::cout << "Enter an age: \n";
    std::cin >> temp;
    age = temp;
}

void displayInOrder( int numbers[], const int SIZE ) {
    std::cout << "\nHere are the ages in order: \n";
    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ) {
        std::cout << numbers[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

void displayInReverse( int numbers[], const int SIZE ) {
    std::cout << "\nHere are the ages in reverse order: \n";
    for ( int i = SIZE - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        std::cout << numbers[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a better explanation, thank you so much

Comment: @dribs No problem at all. When I was new to programming I had to learn the hard way with very minimal assistance so I don't mind helping out those who are new to the craft where I can with what I can.

Comment: Funny you say that, I feel like a lot of people on here forget what it was like being new. Almost everytime I post on stack overflow I get downvoted and trolled in the comments by people who have the ability to help me but don't. I mean I have a B+ in my computer science class but they love to make me feel SO stupid. Anyways, I was drowning and you were my life raft. After reviewing your code a do while makes perfect sense, even though I've been doubting myself all day, I was pretty close to get it working. You not only fixed a program but you renewed my programming confidence. Thanks again.

Comment: @dribs I have no formal education, no degree, all self taught and my field of study is 3D graphics programming, physics simulation, animation and the like.